# Android Back button on webview kills app

Tags: android, button, webview, kill, back

*Solved
I just had to publicly declare my webview variable for my back button class to work correctly.  Thanks for the help

I've got a unique setup with the webview class and everything I've googled I've gotten nowhere.

I'm using buttons to launch webview's and I'm getting the issue that when I press the back button to return to my main app screen it will just kill the app.  I have added some code in at the bottom to try and fix my issue but it has not worked.

btw the below code has been updated to what is currently working for me.

```
package my.android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MobileAppActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
WebView wb;
public void onMyButtonClick01(View view)  
    {  
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pay your dues here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        wb = new WebView(this);
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.link1.html");
        setContentView(wb);           
    }       
public void onMyButtonClick02(View view)  
{  
    Toast.makeText(this, "Re-Sign here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    wb = new WebView(this);
    wb.loadUrl("http://www.link2.html");
    setContentView(wb);

}  
public void onBackPressed () {
    if(wb != null) {
        if(wb.canGoBack()) {
             wb.goBack();
        } else {
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             wb = null;
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: What version of the Android API have you targeted?

Comment: Well, the main app screen has two buttons that launch webviews, upon hitting the back button in a webview my app will just get killed, i want it to go back to the main screen rather than just get killed.  the target API is 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're saving off `wb` elsewhere? Not sure how you're accessing that from `onBackPressed()`. Let's say you *do* have a way to fetch it.

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    if(wb != null) {
        if(wb.canGoBack()) {
             wb.goBack();
        } else {
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
             wb = null;
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not because using your code I still get "wb cannot be resolved to a variable" Is there no way to globally declare those variables?  Sorry I'm new to Java I'm used to .net

Comment: I don't get how your code was working before, then :). That's why I mentioned it. 

There's no reason you couldn't declare a `WebView` field in your class and store it there. Move your `WebView wb;` out of your listeners and to the top. Then in your `onClick()` do `wb = new WebView(this);`.

Not the cleanest thing in the world, but then the more Android-centric way of doing what you're trying to do would be to launch a new Activity instead of replace your content view. Then back would be handled appropriately be default :).

Comment: I'm probably still missing something then, from what I understood of your comment I'm still getting some variable errors and such.

I moved `WebView wb;` outside of the onbuttonclick and placed it in the OnCreate statement. However I still get errors, i'll update my main post with the errors

Comment: Nope, move it outside onCreate(). Like so: `public class MobileAppActivity extends Activity {   WebView wb;`